# Typescript an argument was not provided

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement inheritance in a game I'm making with typescript (pixi.js) but I'm getting stuck on this error. I have a class, Dog, with the following code:

```js
export class Dog extends Enemy {
  //private game: Game;
  //private speed: number = 0;

  constructor(texture: PIXI.Texture, game: Game) {
    super(texture);
    this.game = game;

  }
```

I also have a class enemy, which the class dog extends to, with the following code:

```js
export class Enemy extends PIXI.Sprite {
  public game: Game;
  public speed: number = 0;

  constructor(texture: PIXI.Texture, game: Game) {
    super(texture);
    this.game = game;
  }
```

But in my dog.ts file I get the following error under the super(texture); part of my code: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
enemy.ts(8, 38): An argument for 'game' was not provided.

I have no idea what this means as I would expect I have given an argument for the game in enemy.ts and I also extend to Pixi.sprite.

Edit: If I change the super in enemy.ts to super(texture, game) I get the following error: if I do this I get the following error: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

I can only put on argument in the super function so I'm afraid this won't fix the problem

Edit 2: Nvm I changed the wrong file

Comment: When you call `super`, it means you're calling the parent's constructor. The parent constructor has two arguments, so you need to provide both of them. So you should call `super(texture, game)` in the Dog class.

Comment: …or rather, omit the `constructor` of the `Dog` class altogether, since it's doing exactly what its superclass (`Enemy`) `constructor` already is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not provide `game` (which is a required argument) in `super`.
In the `Dog` class add `game` as the second argument in `super`:

```js
super(texture, game);
```

Comment: If I do this I get the following error: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

Comment: Did you do that in the `Dog` class?

Comment: No I'm sorry in the enemy this fix works

Answer (score 1):

Well, the constructor of `Enemy` expects two arguments in input: `texture: PIXI.Texture, game: Game` but you are giving only the first one.

So, in your `dog.ts` from

```
super(texture)
```

Modify to

```
super(texture, game)
```

The same error may appear in Enemy class if the `Pixi.Sprite` expects the same two arguments.